# Agora servers suddenly gives errors

Tags: agora.io

First, the server in sending an Audio message stopped working with return this error:

{type: 503, message: 'internal error'}

Although I should mention the file uploads without a problem.
After few hours, some of chatroom options began to having issues too. joining the chatroom with a user that is not already in the member list resulted in error:

{type: 17, data: '{"error":"group_authorization","timestamp":1704572…to do this, group member permission is required"}', message: '{"error":"group_authorization","timestamp":1704572…to do this, group member permission is required"}'}

but it didn't require member permission before.

Adding the user to the member list seems to solve this issue but I have no idea how to do that for every new user that registers.

Joining the chatroom fails, but users can send and receive messages for some reason. joining the chatroom returns error :
{data: '', type: 16, message: 'websocket has been disconnected'}

I've been waiting for a few hours, I tried creating another project in a different server, but nothing seems to have changed. As I mentioned it happened suddenly. I'm guessing maybe it will be fixed tomorrow or something, but I'm not sure.